# When multiple workflows run simultaneously in Git Action, can I make them run one at a time?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, testflight, fastlane

I'm building CI/CD using Git Action (uploading to TestFlight)
I designed the logic of using FastLane to bring the latest build number and then + 1.

The problem occurs with the latest Build Number when multiple workflow runs simultaneously.

This is because multiple workflows import the same number from TestFlight before the latest Build number is updated.

To do this, I want workflow to run one at a time.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Consecutive Workflow Action](https://github.com/mktcode/consecutive-workflow-action)

```yaml
jobs:
  consecutiveness:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: mktcode/consecutive-workflow-action@e2e008186aa210faacd68ec30f6ac236f7e2f435
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

  # your other jobs
  something:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [ consecutiveness ]
    steps:
    # ...
```

> `GITHUB_TOKEN` is needed to avoid rate limitation issues when performing API calls (to check the previous workflow run). Make sure you read the security note in the repository’s Readme.